# How to prevent react state overwrites due to asynchronous code and websocket race condition?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, race-condition, recoiljs

I'm building a react app with recoiljs as my state manager and I need to fetch data from a web socket and update the state accordingly. The reason I'm not using a regular array is that I need to share state across my components.

To elaborate, the component has a WebSocket connection and will have data streaming into it. It then needs to update an array by pushing the received data. The problem is due to the component lifecycle or something, the state gets written incorrectly and this is what I think happens

1. Response 1 gets received and setState([...state, data]) is called
2. Response 2 then gets received and setState([...state, data]) is called
3. The state is actually set by Response 1
4. The state is set by Response 2

The problem is when response 2 comes in and setState is called, it has an old version of the state that doesn't include Response 1.

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this. Here is the stripped-down code.

```js
import {atom} from "recoil"
import {useRecoilState} from "recoil"
const WebSocket = require("isomorphic-ws");

const statusAtom = atom<string[]>({
    key: "statusAtom",
    default: []
});


function Component() {
    const [status, setStatus] = useRecoilState(statusAtom);

    const functionCalledAfterButtonPress = () => {
        ws.onmessage = function incoming(res: any) {
            console.log(res.data); // for debugging
            
            setStatus([...status, res.data]);
        };
    }
}
```

Note that I am not including things other events like `ws.onopen` and return statements or whatnot and that the atom declaration and component declaration are in different files.

Comment: As a general rule, if a state change is dependent on the state's previous value, always use the function argument to ensure the state change uses the correct and latest state value. i.e. `setStatus(prevState => [...prevState, res.data]);`

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444 that fixed my problem!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add *FIXED* or *SOLVED* to the title or to edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution that you want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more informatino. If you no longer want help with this question and don't want to share the solution, you can delete the question using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jayce444 said, the way to solve this is instead of using `setStatus` with an already computed value, `[...status, res.data]`, I should instead pass in a lambda statement that is called when the state is updated.

Instead of:
`setStatus([..status, res.data])`

Use: `setStatus(prevStatus => [...prevStatus, res.data])`

Comment: I agree with the answer. Just want to add, another benefit of using this method to set state value is to ensure the updating sequence.